# In react component how I can map the json property which is array of object?

Tags: json, reactjs, express, create-react-app

Actually, I am new in react development and I want to show product page with it's summery but in JSON I have arrays of an object (maybe, shown in code). When I try to use .map I got an error like the prop is undefined.

I have JSON object like below

```
{
      "id": 794,
      "name": "Pellentesque habitant morbi",
      "description": "<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>\n",
      "short_description": "<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>\n",
      "sku": "1000",
      "price": "200",
      "categories": [
        {
          "name": "Best Seller"
        }
      ],
      "regular_price": "21.99",
      "tags": [
        {"name" : "Books Online"},
        {"name" : "Ebooks"},
      ],
      "images": [
        {
          "src": "https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/T_2_front-4.jpg",
        },
        {
          "src": "https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/T_2_back-2.jpg",
        }
      ],
      "author": "Mo. Ra. Walambe"
    }
```

In my component render method, I am doing this

```
rendor(){
 var tags = [];
 const prodSum = this.props.product;
 tags = prodSum.tags.map( (tag) => {
     return <li>{tag.name}</li>;
 });

 return(
         <h1 className="product_title">{prodSum.name}</h1>
         <span className="posted_in">
            Categories: <ul>{tags}</ul>
         </span>
 );
};
```

error is : prodSum.tags is undefined where I am able to show prodSum.name

Why it is not working with array.

I want to display the list of tags

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(prodSum)` after defining it?

Comment: How do you pass the `product` prop to your component?

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb `{id: 794, name: "Pellentesque habitant morbi", description: "<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus … mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>↵", short_description: "<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus … mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>↵", sku: "1000", …}`

Comment: @devserkan I am fetching product data from express api. after that I am passing it to component. `<ProductSummery product={props.product}/>'

Comment: Do you see the `tags` array in your `console.log`. If yes, then you should render your component conditionally since you are getting it from a remote place and in the first render it is undefined.

Comment: Post the parent component where you are calling ProductSummery component.

Comment: You are fetching data from server, while data is not fetched prodSum.tags is `undefined`, it will have value once you get the data from server. You can set default value for tags `[]` in the parent component, or in this component do something like this: `const t = prodSums.tags || []`, then `tags = t.map(...)`

Comment: @ravibagul91 Thanks for the helping me I think devserkan has solved this issue below very well. Thanks for kind help once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a blind suggestion as I do in my comment, you can conditionally render your component.

```js
const product = {
  id: "794",
  name: "Pellentesque habitant morbi",
  description:
    "<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>\n",
  short_description:
    "<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>\n",
  sku: "1000",
  price: "200",
  categories: [
    {
      name: "Best Seller"
    }
  ],
  regular_price: "21.99",
  tags: [
    {
      name: "Books Online"
    },
    {
      name: "Ebooks"
    }
  ],
  images: [
    {
      src: "https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/T_2_front-4.jpg"
    },
    {
      src: "https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/T_2_back-2.jpg"
    }
  ],
  author: "Mo. Ra. Walambe"
};

function fakeApi() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(product), 2000));
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    product: null,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fakeApi().then(product => this.setState({ product }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Product product={this.state.product} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function Product(props) {
  const { product } = props;
  if (!product) return <div>Getting the product...</div>;
  
  const tags = product.tags.map(tag => {
    return <li>{tag.name}</li>;
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="product_title">{product.name}</h1>
      <span className="posted_in">
        Categories: <ul>{tags}</ul>
      </span>
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Do not think about the `fakeApi` part, I'm just simulating the fetch part there. I'm not sure how do you initialize the `product` state in the parent component but as you can see I'm doing it as `null`. So I can check its existence in the child component. If no `product` yet I'm rendering a piece of temporary information. After fetching the product child component is rerendered and return the product information.

As you can see in the comments there can be other scenarios. For example, you can set the initial state to `{}` and check for its properties' existence, like `tags` or set them to empty values like `[]` for the first render.

Using conditional rendering is common usage. React can deal with `undefined` values, there isn't any problem with that. This is why `prodSum.name` is not a problem, since it is `undefined`. But Javascript can't deal something like `undefined.someValue`. Because you are trying to get `someValue` from `undefined` and this is not possible. `prodSum.tags[0].name` is `undefined.name` here.

Comment: Hey, @devserkan It did work for me, I think checking for the data is available or not made it woked. Code has been executing before the data is getting to it, and as you said once the data get fetched it get updated in dom, thanks, bro. Thank you so much

Comment: You are welcome. You will use this approach all the time.